# How can I localize the text used as tool tips of vaadin richtext area?

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

In the [official documentation](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.richtextarea.html) they suggested to use css for localizing the tool tips of vaadin richtext area and it says:

> Localizing RichTextArea Toolbars
>
> The rich text area is one of the few components in Vaadin that contain
>   textual labels. The selection boxes in the toolbar are in English and
>   currently can not be localized in any other way than by inheriting or
>   reimplementing the client-side VRichTextToolbar widget. The buttons
>   can be localized simply with CSS by downloading a copy of the toolbar
>   background image, editing it, and replacing the default toolbar. The
>   toolbar is a single image file from which the individual button icons
>   are picked, so the order of the icons is different from the rendered.
>   The image file depends on the client-side implementation of the
>   toolbar.

```
.v-richtextarea-richtextexample .gwt-ToggleButton
.gwt-Image {
  background-image: url(img/richtextarea-toolbar-fi.png)
                    !important;
}
```

I've downloaded the toolbar background image.
My question is how can I localize the string used for the tool-tips of the Rich Text Area tool bar? Or is there  any vaadin add-ons that can be used as a replacement of Rich Text Area with language localization feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Vaadin Addon - Wrapper for [CK Editor](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/ckeditor-wrapper-for-vaadin).

[Here](http://open.esignforms.com/Vaadin7CKEditor/) you can find online demo. It automaticaly localizes to my browser language.

You can find more information on [official CKEditor site](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: Finally I was able to localize it